# What's the saying that those who scream loud aren't the most dangerous ones?

Tags: phrase-request, translation

There is a Polish saying

> Im pies mniej szczeka, tym bardziej gryzie.

Literally translated:

> The less dogs barks, the more it bites

which means that not those people are the most dangerous, that scream load, but those, who remain silence (or, you shouldn't be afraid of someone who is just screaming).

What is the English equivalent of that saying?

Comment: You seemed to have asked two questions in one here. One phrase for people who are quiet but dangerous. And, one phrase for people who are very loud but not dangerous.

Comment: But the original phrase means both, at least AFAIK

Comment: Similar, but not identical: "Still waters run deep."

Comment: In German there is the saying: `Hunde die bellen, beißen nicht` (Barking dogs don't bite)

Answer (score 7):

> It's always the quiet ones

or

> [Beware the quiet ones](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/BewareTheQuietOnes)

Answer (score 3):

In English, we sometimes say:

> His bark is worse than his bite.

or sometimes this shortened form:

> all bark, no bite

but that only covers the second half of the Polish saying – that the loud ones aren't very dangerous. The part about the quiet ones being more dangerous is not usually inferred in English.

To describe quiet but dangerous, you could use the metaphor *like a lion about to pounce* (or any other predator that stalks its prey). It's not necessarily an often-quoted saying, but it is an often-used metaphor. It goes back at least as far as the Old Testament:

> He lies in wait like a lion in cover; he lies in wait to catch the helpless (Psalms 10:9)
>
> Like a bear lying in wait, like a lion in hiding, he dragged me from the path and mangled me and left me without help. (Lamentations 3:10-11)

but is still used today, such as [this blogger](http://educationmaze.blogspot.com/2008/05/like-lion-ready-to-pounce.html) used as a title:

> Like A Lion Ready To Pounce

or [this one](http://theunjustmedia.com/Islamic%20Perspectives/July12/Shi%27ah%20Is%20Like%20A%20Lion%20That%20Is%20Ready%20To%20Pounce,%20Beware%20Of%20Shi%27ah%27s%20Plots!!!.htm):

> Shi'ah Is Like A Lion That Is Ready To Pounce

or [this one](http://ravinonindia.tumblr.com/post/33369768747/narendra-modi-indias-lion-is-about-to-pounce-to-mp):

> Narendra Modi: India’s lion is about to pounce to MP